# How to plot a vortex indicator from a different timeframe in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am looking to plot the vortex indicator using values from a different timeframe.
So far, it is plotting values but they don't match the actual values from that timeframe.
At the moment, I am looking to plot the Vortex Indicator values from the Weekly timeframe while looking at the Daily Timeframe (or even intraday).

This is the standard code for the Vortex Indicator,

```
period_ = input(14, title="Period", minval=2)

VMP = sum( abs( high - low[1]), period_ )
VMM = sum( abs( low - high[1]), period_ )
STR = sum( atr(1), period_ )
VIP = VMP / STR
VIM = VMM / STR

plot(VIP, title="VI +", color=#3BB3E4)
plot(VIM, title="VI -", color=#FF006E)
```

This is what I have tried, plots incorrect values.

```
period_ = input(14, title="Period", minval=2)
[weekly_high, weekly_low, weekly_close] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", [high, low, close], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)

pine_atr(length) =>
    trueRange = na(weekly_high[2])? weekly_high[1]-weekly_low[1] : max(max(weekly_high[1] - weekly_low[1], abs(weekly_high[1] - weekly_close[2])), abs(weekly_low[1] - weekly_close[2]))
    rma(trueRange, length)

weekly_VMP = sum( abs( weekly_high[1] - weekly_low[2]), period_ )
weekly_VMM = sum( abs( weekly_low[1] - weekly_high[2]), period_ )
weekly_STR = sum( pine_atr(1), period_ )
weekly_VIP = weekly_VMP / weekly_STR
weekly_VIM = weekly_VMM / weekly_STR

plot(weekly_VIP, title="VI +", color=#3BB3E4)
plot(weekly_VIM, title="VI -", color=#FF006E)
```

Any kind of help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed the security function directly with the Vortex values:

```
//@version=4
study("Vortex",overlay=true)

period_ = input(14, title="Period", minval=2)

VMP = sum( abs( high - low[1]), period_ )
VMM = sum( abs( low - high[1]), period_ )
STR = sum( atr(1), period_ )
VIP = VMP / STR
VIM = VMM / STR

plot(VIP, title="VI +", color=#3BB3E4)
plot(VIM, title="VI -", color=#FF006E)

[weekly_VIP, weekly_VIM] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", [VIP, VIM], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off) // Repaint
//[weekly_VIP, weekly_VIM] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", [VIP[1], VIM[1]], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off) // Won't repaint

plot(weekly_VIP, title="VI +", color=#3BB3E4)
plot(weekly_VIM, title="VI -", color=#FF006E)
```

Note that this way you will get the latest Weekly values of Vortex, but indicator would repaint. To avoid that you have to use previous weekly candle's vortex value (commented line)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Pine Script is so confusing with how it does this. It *looks* like you're passing the daily value into the `security()` function, but somehow you're actually passing a formula used previously into the function to be used again on the weekly time scale. Strange logic in my opinion, but yes it seems to work! It's explained more in the docs, see: [Context switching and the security function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html)